# How can I format a Tufte handout with footnotes instead of sidenotes?

Tags: footnotes, tufte

I write most of my essays in a Tufte handout using the fullpage command. For the latest one, I need footnotes instead of sidenotes or endnotes. Is there an easy way to modify the template (or preferably add something to the preamble) to make this work?

Comment: Welcome! Isn't one of the reasons to use Tufte to use sidenotes? Wouldn't it be easier to use a different class?

Comment: It's definitely easier to use a different class (which is what I usually do when I need footnotes.) But documents in Tufte handouts are just so _pretty_.